# spring boot swagger request param time

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-2.0, springdoc-openapi-ui

Using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.11</version>
</dependency>
```

In controller I have this request param setup:

```
@RequestParam(value = "end_time", required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.TIME) LocalTime endTime)
```

In swagger it is required `string($date-time)`, how to make it `string($time)`?

For date I use `@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)` and it is working right.

Comment: OpenAPI Specification (and, consequently, Swagger Java annotations) doesn't have a built-in type/format for "time", it only has the "date-time" and "date" formats. I guess you need to annotate this parameter as just a `string`, something like `@Parameter(name = "end_time", in = ParameterIn.QUERY /*or whatever*/, schema = @Schema(type = "string", example="01:30:00.000-05:00"))`.